# Answering to zimmun twice

Tags: halacha, zimun

In a Suda shlishit of 30 people, one person had to leave and 9 answered to his Zimmun "Nevarech elokeinu...".

What should these 9 people answer to the general Zimmun later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shulchan Arukh, Orach Chayyim 200:1:

> שלשה שאכלו כאחד אחד מפסיק על כרחו לשנים ועונה עמהם ברכת זימון ואפילו
>   לא רצה להפסיק מזמנין עליו בין עונה בין אינו עונה כל שהוא עומד שם אבל
>   שנים אין חייבים להפסיק לאחד והלכך אין חיוב זימון חל עד שיתרצו להפסיק
>   ולברך ואם לא רצו להפסיק וזימן הוא עליהם לא עשה כלום ואם לא רצו להפסיק
>   אף הוא אינו רשאי לברך ולצאת לשוק עד שיגמרו השנים ויזמן עליהם שהרי כבר
>   נתחייב הוא בזימון והיאך יברך בלא זימון:

My summary of the above:

1 person must stop his meal to bentch with the other 2, but 2 people are not obligated to stop eating to bentch with 1 person. Therefore, if that 1 person maid a zimun anyway, it's as if he accomplished nothing. And if the other 2 didn't want to stop eating, it is not appropriate for him to bentch and go to the market, because (since he is sitting with 3 people,) he is required in zimun, and how can he bentch without a zimun?

I infer that was is stated with 1 person vs. 2 is similar to what would happen with 1 vs. 9. I also inferred from your description, that the other 9 didn't stop eating, either. Therefore, it seems that the person "forced" his zimun, and bentched without an appropriate zimun (it is as if he did nothing). The others that answered him anyway, seemed to have accomplished nothing at all, as it seems to be an "inappropriate" zimun.

Therefore, the other 9 should answer regularly at the "second" zimun, when the majority of people agree to complete the meal.